# iOS: change background color using multiple buttons

Tags: ios, select, button, background

I am trying to change background color randomly as an effect overtime any of the buttons on the screen are tapped.
I would like to control this effect with an On/Off UIButton.
Tapping ChangeColorButton just logs “Off” never “On”. Not sure what to do? thanks everyone!!

edited code so far!!
in .h

```
@property(nonatomic,readwrite) BOOL shouldChangeColor;

in .m
- (IBAction)ChangeColorButton:(UIButton*)sender {

   // self.shouldChangeColor = !sender.selected;
   sender.selected = !sender.selected;
    if(sender.selected)
    {
        NSLog(@"Switch is ON");
        //Make it off now
      //  sender.selected=NO;
   //    self.shouldChangeColor=TRUE;



    }
    else

        NSLog(@"Switch is OFF");
    //Make it on now
   // sender.selected=YES;
    self.shouldChangeColor=TRUE;

        }

- (void)randomColor{
    int r = arc4random() % 255;
    int g = arc4random() % 255;
    int b = arc4random() % 255;

    UIColor *color = [UIColor colorWithRed:(r/255.0) green:(g/255.0) blue:(b/255.0) alpha:1.0];

    [self.view setBackgroundColor:color];

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are not changing the selection of the button

```
- (IBAction)ChangeColorButton:(UIButton*)sender {
    //self.shouldChangeColor = sender.selected;
    sender.selected = !sender.selected; //If you do this
    if(sender.selected)
   {
      self.shouldChangeColor=YES;
      NSLog(@"Switch is ON");
      //Make it off now
      //sender.selected=NO; You Don't have to do this
      [self randomColor];//If you want to change the color when switch is on

   }
    else{
      self.shouldChangeColor=NO;
      NSLog(@"Switch is OFF");
      //Make it on now
      //sender.selected=YES; You Don't have to do this
      [self.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackcolor]];//Check the syntax
    }
}
```

Now from anywhere Call this function to change the color `[self randomColor];`

```
- (void)randomColor{
if(self.shouldChangeColor){


int r = arc4random() % 255;
int g = arc4random() % 255;
int b = arc4random() % 255;

UIColor *color = [UIColor colorWithRed:(r/255.0) green:(g/255.0) blue:(b/255.0) alpha:1.0];

[self.view setBackgroundColor:color];
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks souvickcse! When adding those line it's works. I also added an ! to !sender.selected. Now the problem is the ChangeColorButton won't turn "off"

Comment: I'll post the code in original port thanks! Updated the code above. Totally hacking things around. thanks so much for help!

Comment: Awesome thanks! Will test it in a few. Driving now. Thanks so much I will accept the answer when back on computer. Thank u!!

Comment: Works great thank you!!! If you don't mind how would I return to the original black background when turning the button Off? Stoked!!